# how to get csv from nested json data

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Hi I am trying to get csv file from nested json array I am also getting csv but problem is seller_name and drop_seller name is showing as [object,object] because of nested json data attaching image file of my csv file[image]
here is my array

```
 {
"id":"1925",
"booking_id":"1442931120",
"appointment_time":"2015-09-29 16:00:00",
"booking_address":"Sector 15 gurgaon",
"booking_type":"later",
"category_id":"9",
"category_name":"Wash & Iron",
"stage":"accepted",
"lat":"74.83908",
"invoice_price":null,
"lon":"87.7333",
"user_name":" ",
"user_mobile_number":"8800292916",
"user_id":"1782",
"booking_time":"2015-09-22 19:09:55",
"price":null,
"seller_id":"52",
"payment_stage":"individual",
"discount":null,
"visting_charge":"0",
"rating":null,
"promo_code":"",
"drop_address":"",
"drop_time":"2015-10-01 20:18:28",
"comments":"",
"platform":"Web",
"order_return":"0",
"cloths_count":null,
"dc_cloths_count":null,
"cloths_weight":null,
"categories":null,
"service_type":"regular",
"category_type":"0",
"seller":{
"name":"Dinesh",
"mobile_number":"9818782536",
"distance":"10",
"lat":"28.4356578",
"lon":"77.1110703",
"id":"52",
"picture":"resources\/seller\/images\/20150709004010_559e2c4248c73.jpg",
"provider_picture":"resources\/seller\/provider-pictures\/logo_559e2c4248d4a.png"
},
"dropSeller":{
"name":"Dinesh",
"mobile_number":"9818782536",
"distance":"10",
"lat":"28.4356578",
"lon":"77.1110703",
"id":"52",
"picture":"resources\/seller\/images\/20150709004010_559e2c4248c73.jpg",
"provider_picture":"resources\/seller\/provider-pictures\/logo_559e2c4248d4a.png"
}
}
```

and here is my javascript file

```
 function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {

            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "MyReport_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

and I am passing an json object as earlier I shown and I am getting csv file also but problem is in seller_name and drop_seller name showing as[object,object] rest data coming right I think it's because these value are in nested json how to get these name any help please

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand your code. Are you treating the object as an array? How should the desired output look like? My guess is that you only parse the parent object for its properties and their values, therfor the two which have objects as values instead a string show up as [object Object]. You would need to build in a check if a property is an object itself and then go a level deeper for reading the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want only the sellers name to be displayed, not every property of it?

If that's the case simply add a check for an object and then show its name instead.

```
for (var index in arrData[i]) {
    var data = arrData[i][index];
    if(typeof data === 'object'){
        data = data.name;
    }
    row += '"' + data + '",';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution and found out it does not work well if the field has null value since type of null returns an object. Try the below solution if somebody still looking for a solution. Hope this helps!

```
 for (var index in arrData[i]) {
        var data = arrData[i][index];
        if(typeof data === 'object' && data != null){
            data = data.name;
        }
        row += '"' + data + '",';
    }
```